# How to secure session_id?

Tags: security, session

I plan not to use HTTPS for my web app. I used digest authentication as method to secure login to my system. And after user being authenticated, I simply send nonce to them periodically(1 min). When users make request, I simply check whether the nonce expires before I send them response.

I want to know whether it is necessary for me to protect users `session_id` in case the attackers replay the nonce or guess out the nonce generation mechanism? And if yes, how do I secure the `session_id`?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [**Session Hijacking**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_hijacking_attack) and [**Fixation**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation)

The best solutions to Session Hijacking/Fixation is:

- Regenerate session identifier at key points. In your case after user login. So, after the user logins, we give him a new session identifier.
  So,in case a hacker hijacked the session id, it would be useless and
  would not work.
- Save User Agent/IP address and compare it against
  the User Agent/IP address used just before login. A hacker would not have the same User Agent/IP address as the legit user. But remember User Agent/IP address can sometimes be faked.
- Last but not the least, destroy old session regularly.

Keeping these in mind, your program will be safe from Session Hijacking/Fixation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have some doubts regarding solution 1 and 3. For solution 1: Even though we give users new session identifier, the attacker can still sniff the new session id in the subsequent request. For solution 3: What is the difference between destroying session and regenerate new session id? Isn't easier just to regenerate the session identifier?